# Undefined index: website Product.php 510 Magento

Tags: magento, export

Suddenly dataflow exports are hanging and not even triggering in Magento 1.9.2.4

I tried the fix here http://thewebsiteguy.xyz/magento-1-9-2-dataflow-export-error-undefined-index-website/ but no joy.

Does anyone have any notion as to what might be going on here?

```
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Object type dataflow/batch_export considered 
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Save before for dataflow/batch_export
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Object type dataflow/batch_export considered 
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Do NOT force Orig Data for dataflow/batch_export
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Object type dataflow/batch_export considered 
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Object type dataflow/batch_export considered 
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Unable to find description for type dataflow/batch_export
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Retrieve description for insert
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Object type adminlogger/log ignored 
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Save before for 
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Object type adminlogger/log ignored 
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Do NOT force Orig Data for 
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Object type adminlogger/log ignored  
2016-09-10T20:42:56+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: website  in /home/josh/public_html/britex/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Parser/Product.php on line 510
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 423

```
change ‘websites’      => ”, to ‘website’      => ”,
```

Line 436

```
change $row[‘websites’] = join(‘,’, $websiteCodes); to $row[‘website’] = join(‘,’, $websiteCodes);
```

Line 438

```
change $row[‘websites’] = $this->getStore()->getWebsite()->getCode(); to $row[‘website’] = $this->getStore()->getWebsite()->getCode();
```

Comment: For consistence when importing data. Change app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php Line 716 and 721 - Change $importData['websites'] to $importData['website'] .